# Add response example in SwashBuckle using methods/filters instead of controller attributes

Tags: .net, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle, redoc

I have an API which controllers are defined inside another project in a NuGet that I don't have control over, so I can't add attributes to the controller method or classes as it is usually done with SwashBuckle .

I need to add the swagger documentation externally from another project using SwashBuckle API methods, like a custom `IDocumentFilter` or `ISchemaFilter`.

The problem comes trying to do the following:

```cs
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(MyClass), (int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(MyClass request)
```

I need to do the same but instead of using the method attribute, using SwashBuckle methods, I'm trying using a custom `IDocumentFilter` with no luck, like so:

```cs
public class MyCustomDocFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
  public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
  {
    var pathInfo = swaggerDoc.Paths.FirstOrDefault(p =>...);
    var operationInfo = pathInfo.Value.Operations.First(op => ...);
    var exampleOperationResponse = operationInfo.Value.Responses.First(op => op.Key == "200");
    exampleOperationResponse.Value.Content.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json, new     OpenApiMediaType {
    // Example = new OpenApiString(@"{ ""someProp"": ""someVal""}"),
    Schema = new OpenApiSchema
    {
        Reference = new OpenApiReference
        {
            Id = typeof(MyClass).Name,
            Type = ReferenceType.Schema
        }
    },

  }
}
```

If I uncomment above's "Example" line, swagger takes it as if the response is a string instead of using the schema for `MyClass` which is what I need. The code works well in SwaggerUI, the issue is that using the ReDoc UI from [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.ReDoc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.ReDoc) shows the following:

Bad response format (what I'm getting):
[image]

Expected good response example format (would require to define the response schema):
[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @CodingMytra I edited the question to add screenshots that shows the issue more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

To add your own response model in response of swagger **operation**, before that you need to add your model to swagger **SchemaRepository**, after that you can create new response, with your model included in it.

See code below, my model: **ErrorResponse**

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public int Code { get; set; }

    public string Detail { get; set; }
}
```

And my swagger **OperationFilter** code:

```
public class YourOperationFilter: IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        // Try to get my model from swagger schema repository
        context.SchemaRepository.TryLookupByType(typeof(ErrorResponse), out var schema);
    
        if (schema is null)
        {
            // Add schema inside if to exclude multiple adding situation
            schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(typeof(ErrorResponse), context.SchemaRepository);
        }
    
        var content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>()
            {
                {"application/json", new OpenApiMediaType { Schema = schema } }
            };
        
        // Add response
        operation.Responses.Add("500", new OpenApiResponse { Content = content });
    }
}
```

Add **OperationFilter** in swagger gen:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
    {
        x.OperationFilter<YourOperationFilter>();
    });
}
```

[see swagger result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2QQf.png)